# issue in return value from web to sqlite in python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Kindly support, I think a wrong value is returned from html form as I input the right username which already exists in sqlite database and comparing isn't executed successfully and returned None value which leads to the first condition and couldn't pass to the 2nd condition as below.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def log():
    if request.method == "POST":
        un = request.form.get("user_name")
        pss = request.form.get("pass")
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Reg.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        user_data = c.execute("select username from users where username=:u", {'u': un, }).fetchone()
        user_pass = c.execute("select pass from users where username =:u", {'u': un, }).fetchone()
        if user_data is None:
            flash("Wrong Username", "danger")
            return render_template("login.html")
        else:
            if user_pass == ('123',):
                flash("You're logged in", "success")
                return redirect(url_for('photo'))
            else:
                flash("Wrong password", "danger")
                return render_template("login.html")

    return render_template("login.html")
```

Comment: did you try to print the variable `un` ? does it contain what you expect? also, have you tried executing the query `select username from users where username='yourusername' `, without bindings, just to see if it works?

Comment: btw, the condition `user_pass == ('123',)` is clearly wrong, I assume you did it just for debug purposes.

Comment: Thanks dear for the reply, I realized that I wrote the input's name of html for un wrong and I've corrected it then it's working and I've corrected also ('123',)